# Remotely connect to Ubuntu Server that is behind NAT Firewall

Tags: networking, server, ssh, remote-access

How can I configure an Ubuntu Server OS (perhaps an application I can install) so that it connects to a third-party service that enables connections back into the Ubuntu Server? I'm basically looking for something like [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/freeremotecontrola/?wt.srch=1&originid=4286&utpk=logmein&destination=/welcome/access/freedom/1/&mcomb=sSVASMBmH%7C11769202%7Clogmein%7Ce%7Ci8rbbhb5l0%7Cc&utm_source=yahoo&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=Logmein&utm_campaign=11769202&cvosrc=ppc.yahoo-gemini.logmein&cvo_kwid=288910317365&cvo_crid=11769202&Matchtype=e) or [VNC Connect](https://manage.realvnc.com/pricing?_ga=2.232608799.1458217231.1495767999-698526750.1495767558) but for Ubuntu Server rather than a Desktop interface. GUI solutions are out of the question.

I know I could accomplish this by setting up a third machine to act as an SSH gateway, but I don't really feel like managing the machine in the middle and making sure it is always online. Plus, with IP addresses that change, I don't feel like messing with DDNS or trying to keep the IP address for the machine in the middle up-to-date.

I also know I could configure the edge router to forward SSH connections to my server. I'm looking for a solution that is more independent of network architecture. The kind I wouldn't have to worry about if someone came along and pushed the reset button on the router.

For argument's sake, let's say I don't have access to the edge router. I have in fact had an ISP that placed me behind its own NAT firewall (think non-first world country); service was terrible. When I was in that situation, I *couldn't* set up DDNS or forward a port because I didn't have an Internet-facing IP assigned to me.

Does anyone know of a third-party service that offers the ability I'm looking for?

Comment: That's a lot of complexity...and extra attack surface...merely to avoid installing a DDNS script once and logging into your router omce.

Comment: Extra attack surface, yes. I'm well aware of that. Complexity, not really. I think the argument for services like LogMeIn or VNC Connect is that they are not complex. I'm not really looking for complex. I'm just wondering if there is an analogous service for systems without a GUI. DDNS may sound like less hassle, but not when your ISP may change your IP multiple times in an hour like some of mine have in the past or better yet, when the ISP doesn't give you an Internet facing IP. I know that sounds absurd, but I had an ISP that did it once (not in the Western hemisphere).