# How to Access Ubuntu Server behind double NAT?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, iptables

My ISP has provided me a private IP and the cable is plugged to wifi router.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 server on my machine. I have read guides that say basically i can connect to my server even when not in LAN ie via internet.

But considering the fact that i am behind a ISP fw / NAT already, i am not sure if it will work in my case as well.

If it does, can some one suggest the best way to set it up, the overall goal is to access applications on my server from internet. I know there are applications such as teamviewer that can help achieve it but i want to know if there is any other method as teamviewer basically a screen mirroring more than remote login.

I searched the askubuntu already and could not find out a proper solution, one guy seems to have almost same problem and no solution on it as well.

[Remotely connect to Ubuntu Server that is behind NAT Firewall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918988/remotely-connect-to-ubuntu-server-that-is-behind-nat-firewall)

Any and All help is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not configure your router as an access point that way you're behind only 1 nat?

Comment: The ISP has provided a PPOE if i disable DHCP rest of the devices does not pick up automatic IP addresses. and if even i am behind 1 NAT, how do i forward port, i do not have access to ISP router

Comment: In order to access from the outside port forwarding is a must. If you can't do it, forget it as it won't happen.

Comment: That is what i thought. But some one suggested creating VPN tunnel might help. So i thought to ask this question here.